# Is Go's crypto/tls ready for production environments?

Tags: ssl, go

There was previously a comment regarding the crypto/tls library in Go not being ready for production which has been quoted in many places but I have not seen any real updates on this issue.

http://grokbase.com/p/gg/golang-nuts/139sqq5hw5/go-nuts-re-go-is-production-ready-but-the-crypto-tls-package-isnt

What is the status today?
Since the comment was made both v1.2 and v1.3 of the language has been released. Has the library matured? Is it considered production ready?

Comment: This is really opinion based, however even in 1.4 (tip) it is still much slower than say nginx, so the recommended way is to use http in go and put nginx in front of it for https.

Comment: That famous quote from the original implementor of TLS support in Go was more about that implementation *not being scrutinized by security experts.* The problem is that getting crypto *done correctly* is hard (random numbers must be truly random, timings of certain calculations matter etc) and while TLS in Go works just OK, you can't know if it has hidden cryptographic flaws. Having said that, I'd point out that ”proven” implementations sometimes fail miserably -- look at Heartbleed and all the fuss which ensued. Or recall ”goto fail” from Cupertino guys.

Comment: And the problem is that getting implementation scrutinized costs plenty of money as security experts are rare and far in between. So either someone has to find (fundraise, anyone?) these money or some business should open its wallet to do the same to be sure Go works good for them. AFAIK, neither of these two things happened yet.

Comment: `crypto/tls` has some things going for it: implements fewer dusty corners than OpenSSL, written by a legit security expert, safer language than C. But, yeah, needs review and C libs are faster for this kind of stuff anyway, so use nginx or something.